# Rebuild Visual Studio Library Project Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that contains multiple projects. One of these projects is a library, which I have added a method to. Within visual studio I can navigate from the method call in my main project to the method in the library, but when I attempt to build/run the solution it gives me a "does not contain a definition for 'My_Method'". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding the whole solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the library project isnt being rebuilt on each run, assuming that the project reference is correctly added (right click on `references` -> `add reference` -> select your library project)

You should make sure that your library is being rebuilt when you run.

To do so :

- Right click on your `Solution`
- Click on `Configuration manager` (approximative translation)
- Make sure that the `build` is checked, if not, check if for the `library` project

Comment: Yeah but no. In your case it could just default to rebuilding, but in other cases, you dont want to do that. An example that isnt directly related => If you have a setup projec in your solution, you surely dont want to rebuild your setup each time you try running your app !

Comment: If you have a setup project and change something in it, wouldn't you want to rebuild it before you run your app?

Comment: No, the setup is a deployment project. you just want to build it when you are going to ship your application. Building a deployment project is prett long, even for tiny applications.

Comment: Ah yes, but my point remains that if I am referencing a library within my program and I change the library, Visual Studio should be smart enough to rebuild it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems you are not rebuilding the library project and/or you are referencing the output binary (dll) directly.  To solve this you can do one of the following

1. Make sure you rebuild the library project, and reference the updated binary/dll
2. Reference the project directly if it's part of your solution, this way, every time you rebuild the dependent project, it will rebuild the library project.  The drawback to this is, if you have too many projects, it will slow you (re)builds

Comment: I was doing 2., assuming that it would rebuild the library project, but it wasn't doing that. I had to rebuild the library project manually, and then run the dependent project. Oh well I guess I will just remember to manually rebuild it.

Comment: @NominSim maybe your VS settings need to be changed, look at `Tools -> Options... -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run`, and change the build settings there.  Though I do recall having a simmilar experience with VS once (over a year ago), I had to recreate the solution/proj to get it to work right.

Comment: @NominSim check in your Configuration manager(right click on your solution) that its building at every run :)

Comment: @squelos That was it, feel free to make your comment an answer and I will accept it. It seems silly to me that Visual Studio doesn't automatically build projects that it knows have changed, especially when it already will allow navigation to modified areas with no warnings/errors.

Comment: @NominSim Yeah, it is as bit weird. It allows navigation because the code is there, and the reference is existing, but while running, it uses the .dll, which hasnt been rebuilt, and therefore, doesnt contain your new code. I added a reply. I had added a reply.