# Why a dll is copied from GAC to project\bin folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

Having the following situation:

- Windows 7 64bit
- Visual Studio 2010
- A solution containing a project in asp.net 2.0
- In the folder:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\CompanyName\
  I have files:

  - Aaa.dll
  - Aaa.pdb
  - Aaa.xml (xmldoc)
    The dll is not referenced in any of my projects in my solution (actually there's only one project in my solution

The problem is that every time I make a build the dll, pdb and xml are copied to the bin folder and I get:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Aaa.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

if I don't delete the dll before running the program.

I have never encountered a similar problem and I have no idea how diagnose it. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I forgot to metion. This dll **is not referenced** in *References* of the project. (I don't see it in  visual studio project explorer under:
MySolution -> MyProject -> References

**Edit** (@chappo thanks for a new insight)
Running MsBuild I see:

```
_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal:
  Copying file from "C:\MyCompany\MyProjects\Project1\App_Code\AjaxControlToolkit.dll" to "bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\MyCompany\Aaa.dll" to "bin\Aaa.dll".
  Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\MyCompany\Aaa.pdb" to "bin\Aaa.pdb".
  Copying file from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\MyCompany\Aaa.xml" to "bin\Aaa.xml".
```

The dll is indeed marked as copy local the question now is where?

Comment: Try setting the Copy to Local Property to false in the reference.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this dll is not referenced in the project. Thanks for mentioning that but that's not the case.

Comment: "*dll is not referenced in my project*" - it must be referenced from *somewhere* otherwise it wouldn't magically appear.

Comment: Isn't that a dll that contains the webpages in compiled form? Download http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ to open the .dll to decompile it and have a look at the code.

Comment: Looks like it's a transitive run-time reference being copied in by devenv.  Does the same happen when you try building the solution from command line with MSBuild?

Comment: @Suraj Singh No it's not a trojan. I have renamed the dll for the purpose of the question to protect my company's secrets

Comment: Are you referencing a dll that is in another project/solution which is not part of the current solution you are building? If so, check the other solution/project to see what the copy local and references in there look like.

Comment: @mortb No the dll contains only helper functions and no webpage.

Comment: @chappo +1 for reminding me to check what's in msbuild. I have edited my question adding a fragment of an output from msbuild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue once. As you have 64 bit system, check if 'Aaa.dll' is 32 bit dll. If it is, then you have to change Application Pool settings in IIS to Enable 32 bits application.

You can find detailed description here: https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/KB/a1114/how-to-enable-32-bit-application-pool-iis-7-dedicatedvps.aspx

Comment: Actually that was the solution to the problem that was blocking development. You are right and get the credit for the answer. Although I still don't know why it's copied everytime I build, I don't want go too much into details. I am satisfied with the current solution. The dll gets copied but I am able to run my app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your solution file.

- Go to  **Build** tab
- Click **Clean Solution**
- And click **Build Solution**

I experienced like this one a long time ago. But in my case, one of my project could not locate the .dll of my another project. I searched for the answer and I only came up on using this method. 
 Try to look here also. [Rebuild Visual Studio Library Project Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826167/rebuild-visual-studio-library-project-reference)

Comment: Cleaning, rebuilding and so on didn't help

Comment: How about deleting your .pdb files and rebuilding your solution file?